# Difference between passing and not passing a view name in the View() method when we return from an Actionresult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

What is the difference between passing and not passing a view name to the `View()` method in an `Action`?

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

**VS**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
```

What does `view()` return in the case of receiving no argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not pass the name of the view it would pass the name of the action. In your case when you write `return View();` it would be like writing `return View("Index");`

This is helpful in case your action name changes. Pass the view name only when you are using a shared view in multiple actions. For other cases leave it empty.